# Dropdown menu doesnt overlapping with the container div

Tags: html, css, iframe

I start to make an web page and i meet a problem: my iframe in which i wanna put my content is overlapping the menu. My menu works fine till now, when i put this iframe

```
<div id="content">
      <iframe name="content" frameborder="0" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;" height="100%" width="100%" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
</div>
```

and the CSS for this is:

```
#content{
    margin-top:77px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    position:absolute;
        }
```

What is wrong? i take all of the elements from this website and i doesn't know where i am doing wrong. The menu is working without the div so i think that the div is problem. Announce me if you need more details.

Comment: Please provide us the dropdown aswell.

Comment: Based on that, it sounds like a `z-index` rule, but without seeing I can't make a definitive answer.

Comment: The menu is too long to put in one comment

Comment: I can give you on private or on jsfiddle the whole code

Comment: You are right, it was a z-index problem. Thank you for your help!